# if class exists in parallel node

Tags: css

I have next html:

```
<div class="a"> 
   <div class="sub_a"> ... </div> 
</div>
<div class="b"> ... </div>
```

How I can apply rule for class `b`, only if class `sub_a` exists? Only in css way.

Comment: You cannot do it.

Comment: @Mr. Alien there is an alternative approach not mentioned in the other question. Please reopen. Also, OP did not ask for a parent selector specifically.

Comment: @TomM There's no other approach without changing the DOM. Also, technically, parent selector approach applies here, so till I don't get the exact reason, I am not reopening it as there are lots of questions like this which ends up having JavaScript/jQuery answers.

Comment: in OPs example, checking for `:empty` should work

Comment: @TomM Won't work either - https://jsfiddle.net/twq5jqts/

Comment: aye it does - https://jsfiddle.net/4o1puaed/1/

Comment: @TomM No it doesn't - https://jsfiddle.net/4o1puaed/3/ :) Also, don't assume that OP has a literal data of `...`, it's just a placeholder here.. he has data in there for sure.

Comment: you obviously need to define two rule blocks. One without `:empty` and the one with `:empty` is for when the sub class does not exist.

Comment: well whatever. Do your worst

Comment: @TomM Not getting your point here, and you don't have to be rude :)

Comment: I was not trying to be rude here. Okay, look. If you want to style `.b` only if `.a` has children, then you define a block for `.a + .b`. After that, you define another block `.a:empty + .b` and reset the rule. This means, the style will only apply if `.a` is not empty.

Comment: Your fiddle does not work because you only have the latter.